# PHP Laravel extending resource routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel routing functionality allows you to name a resource and name a controller to go with it. I am new to Laravel and would like to know if anyone knows how to extend the resources method in the route class provided.

Basically say I have: (which works fine)

```
/invoices
```

But say I want:

```
/invoices/status/unpaid
```

How is this achievable?

To see the basics of what I am doing check:
http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resource controllers tie you into a specific URLs, such as:

- GET|POST `/invoices`
- GET|PUT `/invoices/{$id}`
- GET `/invoices/create`
- and so on [as documented](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

Since, by convention, `GET /invoices` is used to list all invoices, you may want to add some filtering on that:

`/invoices?status=unpaid` - which you can then use in code

```
<?php

class InvoiceController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $status = Input::get('status');
        // Continue with logic, pagination, etc
    }

}
```

If you don't want to use filtering via a query string, in your case, you *may* be able to do something like:

```
// routes.php
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'invoice'), function()
{
    Route::get('status/unpaid', 'InvoiceController@filter');
});

Route::resource('invoice', 'InvoiceController');
```

That might work as the order routes are created matter. The **first** route that matches will be the one used to fulfill the request.

Comment: Brilliant solution and explanation. I didn't know if the resource would take over the whole "invoice" segment. Thanks.

Comment: It does, see my edit of the code. Per the documentation, you must define the additional routes before the Route::resource call. see http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers